# Create multiple rows of divs

Tags: css

I'd like to create a 2x2 setup, consisting of 4 div elements.  See my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QXqEG/) for my test so far using `inline-block` for my display.  I'd like to have "div 3" and "div 4" directly below 1 and 2, respectively.  Is there a way to do this without floats?

HTML:

```
<div class = "blocks">
    div 1
</div>

<div class = "blocks">
    div 2
</div>

<div class = "blocks">
    div 3
</div>

<div class = "blocks">
    div 4
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.blocks {
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 1px red;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Do you have set widths that will never change, or are they responsive?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put the blocks in a container div, and give it a fixed width.

```
.wrap{
    width:210px;
}

<div class='wrap'>
    <div class = "blocks">div 1</div>
    <div class = "blocks">div 2</div>
    <div class = "blocks">div 3</div>
    <div class = "blocks">div 4</div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9wsqK/)

Comment: This could lead to a messy layout since you're leaving a whitespace on the right side.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your divs are fixed width.  Simply wrap them in a containing element, then limit the width of that element so that only two can fit on one line.  This could easily be modified to fit 3 width wise, or 4 width wise or whatever you so choose for that matter.

Here is a JSFiddle assuming your boxes are 100PX wide.

http://jsfiddle.net/QXqEG/4/

**CSS:**

```
.container { width: 210px; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class = "blocks">
    div 1
</div>

<div class = "blocks">
    div 2
</div>

<div class = "blocks">
    div 3
</div>

<div class = "blocks">
    div 4
</div>
</div><!-- end container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/QXqEG/7/

Like this?

```
<div style="width: 210px;">
    <div class = "blocks">
    div 1
</div>

<div class = "blocks">
    div 2
</div>

<div class = "blocks">
    div 3
</div>

<div class = "blocks">
    div 4
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your jsFiddle link is the same as the one in the question. You have to click "Fork" after you make changes to get a new link for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `<div>` that will contain the 2x2 divs you want.

Like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="column">
  <div class = "blocks">
    div 1
  </div>

  <div class = "blocks">
    div 2
  </div>

  <div class = "blocks">
   div 3
  </div>

  <div class = "blocks">
    div 4
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#column {
  position: absolute;
  width: 210px; height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000
}
```

see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QXqEG/10/)

Answer (score 0):

wrap the blocks that you want in the same row with a div and maybe play with their width

```
<div class="row">
  <div class = "blocks">
     div 1
  </div>

  <div class = "blocks">
    div 2
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class = "blocks">
    div 3
  </div>

  <div class = "blocks">
    div 4
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of ways to do this. One way would be to simply ad a `<br />` tag between div 2 and div 3, another would to be to nest every row in a new `<div>` like below. It really depends on what you are planning to do.

```
<div id= "row1">
    <div class = "blocks">
        div 1
    </div>

   <div class = "blocks">
        div 2
    </div>
</div>

<div id= "row2">
    <div class = "blocks">
        div 3
    </div>

    <div class = "blocks">
        div 4
    </div>
</div>
```